# KeyError for 'id' field when ModelForm CheckboxSelectMultiple choices are 'id'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am new to Django. I have a form where I want to have list of 'id's of model items as choices of CheckboxSelectMultiple field. Here is my example

Models.py

```
class TryDjango(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

Views.py

```
class trydjango_view(View):
    template_name = 'trydjango.html'
    failed_template = 'generic_error.html'

    viewContext = {
        "title" : "Page title ",
        "columnNames" : ["Name"],
        "url" : 'trydjango',
        'loginInfo' : 'logout',
    }

    def get(self, request):
        self.viewContext['deleteTryDjangoForm'] = \
            deleteTryDjangoForm(prefix='delete')
        login_result = getLogin(request)
        self.viewContext.update({'loginInfo' : login_result['loginInfo']})
        return render(request, self.template_name, self.viewContext)
```

trydjango.html template

```
{% block tableHeader %}
  <tr>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <td>

      <form id="delItem" action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Delete Django"
          name="{{deleteTryDjangoForm.prefix}}"/>
      </form>

    </td>
    {% endif %}
    {% for columnName in columnNames %}
      <th>{{columnName}}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>

{% endblock %}
```

ModelForms.py

```
    class deleteTryDjangoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    myPrefix ='delete-'

    class Meta:
        model = TryDjango
        fields = ['id']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(deleteTryDjangoForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        sportSeriesList = listOfSportSeries()
        print(sportSeriesList)
        self.fields['id'].widget = \
            forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=[(1,1)]) #<<-- Line 399 in the error
```

Finally the error I am getting

```
KeyError at /trydjango/
'id'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/trydjango/
Django Version: 2.0.7
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 'id'
Exception Location: /Users/sbt/dev/trydjango/src/myPrjApp/modelforms.py in __init__, line 399
```

Where line 399 is the line "forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=[(1,1)])" from my form.

The form doesn't give this error if I change the field from 'id' to 'name'. I have few other models whose primary keys are not the 'id' fields. I can delete those model items using the corresponding primary keys. However, the form fails only if the primary key is 'id'.

Please help me with my mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` in a model is not editable, so a ModelForm doesn't create a field for it.

You don't need a ModelForm here anyway. That's for creating new instance or editing existing ones. You just want a standard form.

```
class deleteTryDjangoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    id = fields.MultipleChoiceField(
       choices=[(1,1)],
       widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that. Appreciate the quick response.